# Manipulating output in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to manipulate what comes out of the select statement in the form of outputting a string rather than a column value if the column value fits a certain rule.

For example in a table of users with the columns -

country, person_id, timestamp

would it be possible to have a select statement that for all countries in South America it outputs the name of the country, however for all countries outside of South America is outputs 'rest of the world', and along side each it has the number of users.

There should only be two columns though, the country column which will either have the name of a south American country or 'rest of the world' and a second column with number of users.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you know what countries are in South America?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first need to add case statement then  count with group by the case statement .
example :

```sql
select case when country_name  in (x1,x2,...) then 'country'
            else 'rest'
    end as country_split
    count(users) as amount_of_users
  from table
group by  case when country_name  in (x1,x2,...) then 'country'
            else 'rest' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when country in ('Surinam', 'Uruguay', 'Guayana', . .. )
             then country else 'rest of world'
        end) as sa_country, count(*)
from t
group by sa_country;
```